# I made a div for a navigation bar and don't know how to pull it down the screen(HTML AND CSS)

Tags: html, css

my code looks like this (My css code)

```
#leftPanel{

    width:300px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:rgba(0,51,255,0.3);
    padding-left:30px;
    padding-top: 200px;
}
```

but the result looks like this:

[image]

i want that blue box to be brought down my screen. Can somebody help me out, thanks

Comment: Share all of the code please. Reproduce that layout for us in your post. What do you mean "brought down my screen"?

Comment: Read about "position". I think "fixed" or "absolute" will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try use viewport height **(vh)** instead of pixels **(px)**:

```
.leftPanel {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100vh; // Here use vh instead of px
  background-color: rgba(0,51,255,0.3);
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-top: 200px;
}
```

If this doesn't work I would paste in the rest of the code to make it easier to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

Try using position: fixed in your css

```
#leftPanel{
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0px;
    left:0px;
    width:300px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:rgba(0,51,255,0.3);
    padding-left:30px;
}
```

It should help you to get your blue box down.